# ADT subtyping in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, algebraic-data-types

Is there an equivalent to the OO notion of subtyping for the ADT pattern as used in Scala?
In particular I would like to add methods to more specialized types. For example, given a generic List ADT:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case class Cons[+A](h: A, t: List[A]) extends List[A]
case object Nil[Nothing]
```

I'd like to define new methods for lists of particular types:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
sealed trait DuckList extends List[Duck] {
    def feed(l: DuckList) = ...
}
```

but then I'd also have to define special data constructors (DuckCons, DuckNil) for these new types, and since case classes don't support (case-to-case) inheritance, there is no way to relate a DuckCons to the generic Cons such that it would work in pattern matching, so the generic methods defined for List wouldn't work for DuckList.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the type class pattern.

For one example, consider how [`Ordering`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering) is implemented. It adds a method -- `compare` -- to a set of closed classes, but it does so not by adding the method directly but, instead, providing an instance that has such a method for that particular class. `Ordering[Int]`, to continue with the example, is implemented like this:

```
trait IntOrdering extends Ordering[Int] {
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int) =
    if (x < y) -1
    else if (x == y) 0
    else 1
}
implicit object Int extends IntOrdering
```

That is, the object `Ordering.Int` (for this is inside the object `Ordering`) implements a method `compare` that takes two `Int` as a parameter. This object is provided implicitly, so that the user does not need to pass it explicitly. `List`'s `sorted` method takes advantage of this:

```
def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: math.Ordering[B]): List[A]
```

Then it can call `ord.compare` on instances of the list to order them. I encourage you to look at `Ordering` to understand what it is doing.

Comment: "This conversion is provided implicitly, so that the user does not need to pass it explicitly.". What conversion? There is simply an implicit parameter, right? No conversion AFAIK.

Comment: @Felix Right, I misspoke.

Comment: so this solution allows extension in the sense of defining type-specific behavior for (previously defined) generic methods, but it doesn't actually allow the definition of new methods right? so I could only implement the `feed` method in my example if it was already available in `List` at least as an abstract method.

Comment: @estolua It allows one to define new method for a type in terms of that type's public methods. If you mean calling `list.feed` instead of `feed(list)`, that distinction is irrelevant. For syntax sake, you can use implicit conversions (also present on `Ordering`), but that's a different concern.